# Android ICS guidelines to emphasize ListView row

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to implement a ListView filled with a specific bus schedule (it's just a list filled with specific times).

What I'm looking for is a proper way (following the guidelines) to highlight/emphasize a specific row to indicate when the next bus arrives.

First I did this changing the background colour of the row, but since this is also used for selection in the contextual action bar, it may look counter intuitive (and also against the ICS guidelines).

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICS native apps often do use a slight change in row background color to highlight active or emphasized rows. See Talk:

[Talk http://developer.android.com/design/static/content/themes_holo_inverse.png](http://developer.android.com/design/static/content/themes_holo_inverse.png)

I would just suggest keeping the same background color but using a subtle change in shade, since ICS selection will use a colored background (light blue in the case of the Nexus.)

Answer (score 0):

How about a colored vertical bar in the left or right of the view?

[image: A color bar to indicate the specific row]

Or perhaps you could get a similar effect using an icon. Circular ones with exclamation marks tend to draw attention.